# Is there a key to go to the next search result that is not on the screen currently?

Tags: search

If i press a bunch of key sequences like this:

```
/term<cr>
```

and there are five matches on the screen currently, i will have to press `n` five times to see the next search result that is not on the screen. Is there a single key (or two) that I can press to emulate pressing `n` five times in the situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd>

Scroll one page forward (downward) in the buffer, then find next match.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it *is* simple, and it doesn't require you to think of the appropriate count for your <kbd>n</kbd> motion.

You can also go the other way with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>.

Since you asked for a single key, you can just make this into a mapping; whatever is most comfortable for you. Maybe something like:

```
noremap <C-n> <C-f>n
```

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> is just an alias for <kbd>j</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Ln to search next instance on the next page and HN to search previous instance on previous page. 
L - Jump to bottom of the screen
H - Jump to the top of the screen

You can map these to any shortcut you want.

Answer (score 0):

n/N support counts, You can use 5n. I recommend to read `:h n`.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the out put from `:h n`

```
n                       Repeat the latest "/" or "?" [count] times.
                         If the cursor doesn't move the search is repeated with
                         count + 1.
                         last-pattern {Vi: no count}
```

You can just use `5n` to go forward or `5N` to go backwards